# Modbus TCP Master-Slave

Tags: tcp

I have a problem with modbus master and slave TCP communication,

On windows computer:
When Master and Slave connect each other they communicate successfuly on 50905->502 ports, when I disconnect to ethernet cable from master device  and connect again ethernet port changing for master like 50908->502 ( than master send ack to slave but least tcp connection alive for the slave (50905->502 ) and anyone close it. Master PC couldnt close before socket, so slave device ended all new connection request for master, slave try to close before connection every connection trying.
Q1) Why pc open new tcp port when on plug ethernet connection ? Why is current communication not resumed from the previous port when the connection is restored? Is that correct situation or not ?
Q2) Should slave manage port close operation, or master responsible for this ?

How can I analyse my problem and solve please help me ?

**EDIT:**

According to command :
I change below values:

```
/* Keepalive values, compliant with RFC 1122. Don't change this unless you know what you're doing */
#ifndef  TCP_KEEPIDLE_DEFAULT
#define  TCP_KEEPIDLE_DEFAULT     1000UL /* Default KEEPALIVE timer in milliseconds */
#endif

#ifndef  TCP_KEEPINTVL_DEFAULT
#define  TCP_KEEPINTVL_DEFAULT    1000UL   /* Default Time between KEEPALIVE probes in milliseconds */
#endif
```

and I add below line in lwipopth.h:

```
#define LWIP_TCP_KEEPALIVE  1// enable "kepp-alive"
```

When I un plug ethernet cable and connect again I get below packets forever. I couldnt solve above solution how can I solve this problem ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2k16.png)

1.40 => slave, other master

Answer (score 1):

If the connection was brutally closed on one side, the other side has
no way of knowing it, so the socket used on that side stays open.

Even after the socket is closed, the operating system keeps the connection
in limbo for some time, so will prevent any other connection from being
accepted for the same quadruplet of
"source address, source port, destination address, destination port".

Under Windows, you may shorten the time a connection stays around by setting
[TcpTimedWaitDelay](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc938217(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

If the code is under your control, the solution is to set the socket option
in the program with
[setsockopt](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt)
like this:

```
setsockopt(socket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR ... )
```

The option `SO_KEEPALIVE` could be useful for the socket to check
periodically if the other side is still connected.

See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1488696/8672) of mine
for how to set Windows to periodically check all sockets for being
still connected on both sides.

Comment: Thank you for your detail. On the slave side control with lwip tcp from me but master side PC . Will I change master or slave side ?

Comment: On one or both sides, as you like. Normally SO_REUSEADDR and TcpTimedWaitDelay are used on the server and SO_KEEPALIVE may be used on both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I will proceed this way.

Comment: I add new updated in my topic. I try to reduce time from slave and it didnt work

Comment: By the way my application using netcon api this is maybe different things include becase when I change the settings i didint see any difference